# how to query records which field A before field B in the doc

Tags: mongodb

Does MongoDB support query like this?

for example I have data like this

```
> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : 1, "x" : 1, "y" : 2, "z" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "y" : 2, "x" : 1, "z" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "z" : 3, "y" : 2, "x" : 1 }
```

now I want to query the records which field `y` before field `x`, that is the last two records.

Does MongoDB support it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following aggregation:

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            keys: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $objectToArray: "$$ROOT" },
                    as: "item",
                    in: "$$item.k"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: { $lt: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$keys", "y" ] } , { $indexOfArray: [ "$keys", "x" ] } ] } 
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            keys: 0
        }
    }
])
```

[$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/?searchProperty=current&query=%24objectToArray) can transform your root document to an array of key-value pairs. Then you can use [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to get the position of `x` and `y` keys and compare them using [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html).

Two things you need to be aware of (based on this [page](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/)):

- Updates that include renaming of field names may result in the reordering of fields in the document.
- Starting in version 2.6, MongoDB actively attempts to preserve the field order in a document. Before version 2.6, MongoDB did not actively preserve the order of the fields in a document.

Comment: Thanks! but I cannot use `$expr` in `$match`, becuase I got the error:`unknown top level operator: $expr`. So I use `$cmp` in `$project` insted: `cmp_y_x: { $cmp: [ { $indexOfArray: [ "$keys", "y" ] } , { $indexOfArray: [ "$keys", "x" ] } ] }`

Comment: @zhuguowei you can use `$expr` in v 3.6, however you found a working solution. Alternatively you can use `$redact` instead of match if you prefer

Comment: actually `$expr` only could use in `query` not in `$match`,please see:https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/index.html